# Revising text file

Tags: text-processing

How can I delete the lines that exceed specific number of letters and characters from a text file ?

For example: In this text file :

```
         a;dskjshdkjhgsdlhb5451candsncas;ldjch;sdkjncl
         zdkcjsd#c
         adsaskad@#s;l35684ad;sjdikm;
         ;okjilh@j
         oieoigsb53454kdsjhcyavscjbkajlknscm;la,
```

How can I delete automatically ( using a command line) all the lines that include only 8 letters and characters? I am asking this question because I have a sort of text files and I want to delete only the lines that have 8 (letters and characters) in it ( it is similar lines between all the files and have the same letters and characters).

Comment: 8 characters or 8 letters? and what about the spaces before and after the lines?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Are the spaces at the beginning of each lne part of your file? Should they count as characters? Should only letters count or any character? Is `         123456789` longer than 8 or is it 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `sed`, `.` matches any character `\{8\}` tells it to match exactly 8 of them. the `^` says match from the beginning of the line and `$` says match til the end of the line, the `d` says delete the line.

```
 sed '/^.\{8\}$/d' file > newfile
```

or if you want to change the existing file, with GNU `sed`:

```
 sed -i '/^.\{8\}$/d' file
```

If you want to delete empty lines as well the `-e` allows you to put multiple expressions in the same command

```
sed -i -e '/^.\{8\}$/d' -e '/^$/d'
```

Comment: ! Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want. Please one more question. How can I delete empty lines?

Comment: Add what you needed and fixed an issue.. you need to have ^ at the beginning and $ at the end of the expression or it will match anything that has at least 8 character, with ^ and $ the whole line must have exactly 8 characters. and the expression "^$" will match lines that have nothing on it.

Comment: and `^[[:space:]]*$` will match lines that are either completely empty or which contain only whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
awk 'length($0) == 8 ' old_file > new_file
```

use 
 - `== 8`  or `!= 8` for equal, not equal.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -vEx '.{8}'
```

Or:

```
awk 'length != 8'
```

Beware of potential problems if your input contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters (like a 0xe9 byte alone in a UTF-8 locale as typical if dealing with files with the wrong encoding).

For GNU `awk`, those bytes will not add up to the value returned by `length`. For GNU `grep`, those lines that contain such byte sequences will not match `.{8}` so those lines will be returned (because of `-v`) or you'll get a *Binary file (standard input) matches* message. You'll have similar problems with GNU `sed`.